# CentOS: Add init script to all default runlevels

Tags: centos, init-script, sysvinit

How can I add specific init script exists in `/etc/init.d/init_script` to all default runlevels?

In debian based distros, this can be achieved by

```
sudo update-rc.d init_script defaults
```

But in CentOS, RedHat, any straight way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure that you mention is based in the SystemV init; CentOs and Red Hat use systemd. The best way to add a init script would be:

```
systemctl enable init_script
```

**For example:**

```
systemctl enable postfix
```

**See:**
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/getting-started-systemctl

Comment: Which runlevel does this mainly affect? Or is there a way to figure out the runlevel that systemctl targeting?

Comment: By default it affects to the default runlevel (by default level 5) also called graphical.target as in systemd the "runlevel" concept changes. For more information about the targets, here is an article: https://access.redhat.com/articles/754933